# Where to install PHP extension on XAMPP?

Tags: php, xampp

I am a PHP and XAMPP noob.  I would like to enable PHP error logging in Chrome.  I have located 2 Chrome extensions that purport to do this.  But each requires that I install libraries on my server.  I am using a local installation of XAMPP as my server, and I am wondering where exactly I need to install these libraries.

The libraries consist of various files and folders, but the important files appear to be PHP files.  In my XAMPP area, there exists a php/ext directory.  But there are no folders or php files in it (only .dll files).  So this didn't seem like the right area.  Correct me if I'm wrong though.

The plugins in-question are PHP Console and FirePHP.  I think there are more, but these 2 appear to have what I need.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general while using xampp, just move your php files/libraries to

> xampp->htdocs(folder)

to make it work.

i.e. .php extensions work inside htdocs folder and its subsidiary folders only.